# Initializing Angular scope variable with array

Tags: angularjs

I am using angularjs for my application.I am passing data in json format to web api.I am having trouble passing multiple selected values in checkbox from angular controller to webapi.

Here is my controller code

```
    $scope.target=[];
    $scope.add_workout_a = function(workout){
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.Target.length; i++) {
            if ($scope.Target[i].Selected) {
                $scope.value = $scope.Target[i].Value;
                console.log($scope.value);//Here i am able to get the 
                value as 0,1,2 if i select 3 values .//
            }
        }

    $scope.cardio_duration=$scope.workout.cardio_duration;
    $scope.primary_muscles=$scope.workout.primary_muscles;
    $scope.target=$scope.value;
    console.log($scope.target);//Here i am not able to get the 
    value.If i select three vales also it is displaying only last
    value that is 2.//

    $scope.time=$scope.workout.selectedTime;
    $scope.days=$scope.workout.selectedDay;

    AdminManageWorkoutService.add_workout_a($scope.cardio_duration,
    $scope.primary_muscles,$scope.target,$scope.time,$scope.days).then(function(response){
    console.log(response);
    //rest of the code
        })
    }
```

Here is the list of Target

```
    $scope.Target = [{
    Name: 'Target1',
    Value: 0,
    Selected: false
}, {
    Name: 'Target2',
    Value: 1,
    Selected: false
}, {
    Name: 'Target3',
    Value: 2,
    Selected: false
}];
```

Here is the html code for Target checkbox

```
    <div class="form-group" data-ng-repeat="target in Target">
    <label for="chkCustomer_{{target.Value}}"><br/>
    <input id="chkCustomer_{{target.Value}}" type="checkbox" data-ng-
    model="target.Selected" />
    {{target.Name}}
    </label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-
    click="add_workout_a(workout)">Submit</button>
```

If i select more than one value in checkbox it is displaying only last value that too in this format.

```
     target:2.
```

But i want to send in this format

```
     target: [0,1,2]
```

Can anyone tell how can i get the selected values from checkbox into $scope.target variable in array format?

Answer (score 0):

at first you must declare  `$scope.value` as a array

```
$scope.value=[];
```

and then `foreach` trough $scope.target and using `push` for add appropriate property to `$scope.value`.

try following

```
$scope.value=[];
angular.forEach($scope.Target ,
  function(item) {
    if (item.Selected)
      $scope.value.push(item.Value);
  }
);
console.log(self.value);
```